# Control properties don't allow to be changed

Tags: c#, winforms

My mainForm contains two buttons(btnLoad & btnChange) and a panel

When the btnLoad is clicked, it loads the other forms(there are 5 different froms with different controlers) into the panel. Let me assume one of it named Form2 which contains a label(labelMessage)

My problem is, when I click the btnChange the following statement won't work.

```
f2.labelMessage.Text = "Button Change Clicked";
```

**My codes are**

```
// codes on mainFrom

private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Form2 f2 = new From2();
   f2.labelMessage.Text = "Button Change Clicked"; //labelMessage's modifier is public

}


private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelDock.Controls.Clear();
    Form f2 = new Form2();
    f2.TopLevel = false;
    panelDock.Controls.Add(f2);
    f2.Show();

}
```

is this wrong?

Comment: Is Form2 already shown?

Comment: Yes.. Form2 is loaded into the panel using btnLoad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Form2 is already shown you should use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of creating a new instance of Form2

```
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
    f2.labelMessage.Text = "Button Change Clicked"; //labelMessage's modifier is public
}
```

From your comment that Form2 is in a panel you can try

```
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = (Form2)panel1.Controls["Form2"];
    f2.labelMessage.Text = "Button Change Clicked"; //labelMessage's modifier is public
}
```

Comment: Problem is after the btnLoad is clicked, the Form2 Loads into the panel and shown.

Comment: @Chathura I think you mean that an exception is thrown if the user clicks btnChange before btnLoad. Am I correct?

Comment: No.. I compiled the code, first loaded the Form2 into the panel and then clicked the btnChange button. but exception occured "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". This is what happened.

Comment: @Chathura Loaded Form2 into a Panel? Is Form2 a Form? Can you show the code you used to do that?.

Comment: @Chathura Even using your code my initial answer still works for me, But try my second code